# google map api in javascript : how to dinamic setCenter in two layer for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
function start()
{
    var lastcenter = map.getCenter();
    for(var i = 0;i<2/*18937*/;i++)
    {   
        var run = lastcenter;
        var lat = run.lat()-(0.00018*i);
        var lng = run.lng();
        for(var j = 0;j<3/*11276*/;j++) 
        {   
            var rlng = lng+(0.00018*j);     
            run = {lat:lat,lng:rlng};
            map.setCenter(run);
            PrintMap();

        }

    }

}
```

**I try to cut many small square from google map，and wanna to setcenter to Visit every square and capture them but the program will setcenter at last point and cut many square for last point，How can i fix it....
demo:https://jsfiddle.net/awalker0215/u0s9kna1/1/
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both html2canvas and setCenter are asynchronous. So your code needs to "wait" until one call has been finished and then proceed further.

It could look something like this

```
<input type="button" value="startCut" onclick="moveMap()">
```

and

```
var i = 0, n = 3;

function moveMap()
{
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        printMap();
    })

    map.setCenter({lat: map.getCenter().lat() - 0.1, lng: map.getCenter().lng() - 0.1});
}

function printMap() 
{           
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("map"), 
    {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) 
        {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))

            i++;

            if (i < n) {
                moveMap();
            } else {
                google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

The problem in this case is that the map sometimes is idle but tiles are still being loaded (note the last image). So it would be better to use timeout.

```
var i = 0, n = 3;

function moveMap()
{
    map.setCenter({lat: map.getCenter().lat() - 0.1, lng: map.getCenter().lng() - 0.1});

    setTimeout(function() {
        printMap();
    }, 200);
}

function printMap() 
{           
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("map"), 
    {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) 
        {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))

            i++;

            if (i < n) {
                moveMap();
            }
        }
    })
}
```